# Find Next Step in Predefined List

Tags: c#

I'm writing some code which helps to automate some manual processes. One of the processes is creating Merge Requests.

Our Git process is generally speaking: Feature Branch -> Development Branch -> Test Branch -> Master Branch.

Initially the code was quite simple:

```
if (source == "test")
  destination = "master";
else if (source == "dev")
  destination = "test";
else
  destination = "dev";
```

Unfortunately we do deviate slightly from time to time by skipping steps (the "order" always remains the same).

So the code is now looking a bit too messy:

```
if (source == "test")
  destination = "master";
else if (source == "dev" && testExists)
  destination = "test";
else if (source == "dev")
  destination = "master"
else if (devExists)
  destination = "dev";
else if (testExists)
  destination = "test";
else 
  destination = "master";
```

This isn't terrible but I do feel we could do something much cleaner that look more like:

```
if (source == "test")
  destination = "master";
else if (source == "dev")
  destination = nextAvailable("test");
else
  destination = nextAvailable("dev");
```

Where next available tries the passed branch but if it doesn't exist will try the next and so on and so forth.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @lastr2d2 here's a slightly revised version of the suggested code which we were able to implement:

```
        var projectBranches = GetProjectBranches();
        var branchWorkflow = new[] { "dev", "test", "master" };
        branchWorkflow = branchWorkflow.Intersect(projectBranches).ToArray();
        var currentPosition = Array.IndexOf(branchWorkflow, sourceBranch);
        string target = branchWorkflow[currentPosition + 1];
```

Comment: Fixed thanks @penguin though it is only to give an indication it's not exactly as is :)

Comment: I would change to a switch statement. Seems like you are asking for a complicated solution to a simple feature.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the switch and why it might be preferable? I guess any time we duplicate code I smell something off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be overkill (a complicated solution) for your current requirement but it's easier to maintain if you are going to change to a different branch strategy.

```
public static string NextAvaliableBranch(string currentBranch)
{
    var predefinedPriorityList = new[] {"dev", "test", "master"};
    // instead of `testExists` or `masterExists`
    // find a way to build the available branch or missing branch list
    var avaliableBranches = new[] {"dev", "master"};
    // var missingBranches = new[] {"test"};
    var priorityBranches = predefinedPriorityList.Intersect(avaliableBranches).ToList();
    // var priorityBranches = predefinedPriorityList.Except(missingBranches);
    
    var currentBranchIndex = priorityBranches.IndexOf(currentBranch);
    if(currentBranchIndex <0){
        return priorityBranches.First();
    }
        
    var nextBranchIndex = currentBranchIndex +1;
    if(nextBranchIndex == priorityBranches.Count){
        return priorityBranches.Last();
    }
        
    return priorityBranches[nextBranchIndex];   
}
```

Comment: This is perfect- thank you! I will see if I can refactor it a tiny bit, but it should scale without having to keep adding if/case clauses etc.

Comment: Just edited the original question to include the solution we used. Didn't need the `if`s which makes it even more slick- thanks again for your help pushing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

[Early return](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8) does wonders in a case like this.

```
string GetDestination(string source, bool testExists)
{
    if (source == "test") return "master";
    if (source == "dev") return testExists ? "test" : master;
    if (devExists) return "dev";
    if (testExists) return "test";
    return "master";
}
```

Comment: Love this. We had something along these lines but not quite as beautiful :) I think the ternary operator concerns me a tiny but but not too much...

Comment: But what if we then added a staging step between Dev and Test? It gets exponentially more complex right?

Comment: With early return, it gets *linearly* more complex, because there is only a single, one-dimensional list of conditions (rather than a nested list). If you add ten more environments and it gets to be too much, you could try implementing a truth table, but that seems like overkill for your example.

Answer (score -1):

Per OP comment:

> Could you provide an example of the switch and why it might be preferable? I guess any time we duplicate code I smell something off...

You could use a switch statement to make the logic more readable:

```cs
switch (source)
{
    case "test":
        destination = "master";
        break;
    case "dev":
        destination = testExists ? "test" : "master";
        break;
    default:
        if (devExists)
        {
            destination = "dev";
            break;
        }
        destination = testExists ? "test" : "master";
        break;
}
```

Even better, wrap it as its own method:

```cs
public string GetDestination(string source, bool testExists, bool devExists)
{
    switch (source)
    {
        case "test":
            return "master";
        case "dev":
            return testExists ? "test" : "master";
        default:
            if (devExists)
            {
                return "dev";
            }
            return testExists ? "test" : "master";
    }
}
```

It depends on how complex your decision tree is but, in general, when you have one variable with a fixed set of possible values, a `switch` statement is the way to go.